# In Java, what exactly constitutes as "initializing a local variable"?

Tags: java

say I have a piece of code in a local method

```
int a = 5, b;
```

and then some code to indirectly initialize B such as

```
if (true) b = 5;  // legal 
if (someBool) b = 10; else b = 7; // legal
if (false) b = 5;  // illegal
```

illegal even though B will always be initialized

```
if (a > 10)
b = 4;
if (a <= 10)
b = 4;
```

My question is what are all of the exact circumstances in which a local variable can be legitimately considered "initialized"?

Comment: The question is too broad at the moment (*'what are all of the exact circumstances'*). The JLS devotes an entire chapter to this, called [Definite Assignment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html).

Comment: The answer is that the compiler can only do so much. So, either explicitly initialize local variables, always, or expect that occasionally the compiler won't be able to make the determination. Your IDE will usually point out what can and can't be determined.

Comment: I'm confused on what you mean by 'illegal' and 'legal'. `if(false) b = 5;` make no sense. `b = 5;` is dead code in that case. I popped this sucker into my IDE, and it printed as it should. I set `someBool` to `false`, printed b, got 7. I set `someBool` to `true`, printed b, got 10.

Comment: @VinceEmigh He means "legal to use" (that is, guaranteed to be initialised) vs not.

Comment: @Radiodef That entire chapter (possibly minus some of the examples) would constitute a correct answer to this question.  In fact, I would consider it the *only possible* correct answer.

Comment: @DavidWallace I agree because the JLS is so meticulous. And merely posting the link would be a link-only answer which I am not a fan of. It's my opinion the OP should rephrase their question.

Comment: @Radiodef `s/phras/mov/` - I don't think Stack Overflow should be duplicating the JLS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A local variable can be considered to be "initialized" if the compiler can easily deduce that every possible code path will lead through a path where the value has been set.

- `if(true)` can be determined to always run.
- `if(false)` can be determined to never run.
- `if/else` can be determined to run at least one of the branches, so you must assign the variable in each branch if you want it to be guaranteed initialized. Same principle applies for `if/else if/.../else`
- `switch` statements will either run one of the possible `case`s, or will hit the `default` case, so if you assign the variable in all of these places then it can be guaranteed initialized.

The Java compiler doesn't bother checking all the possible values of each variable at various points in the method when making this determination, because variables are *variable*--they can change. However, if values can be considered *constant* then it can safely assume they won't change.

For example, the compiler doesn't care if you assign a variable and never change it in your code:

```
boolean val = true;
if(val) {
     b = 5;
}
```

Debuggers and things make it possible for you to change the value of `val` on-the-fly, so the compiler doesn't make any assumptions here. However, if you make `val` *constant*, by declaring it `final` and initializing it with a constant or literal value, then the compiler will treat it exactly the same as if you'd used the constant value in code.

```
final boolean val = true;
if(val) {                 // Same as if you'd said `if(true)`
     b = 5;
}
```

Such constants can be chained, as well, and the compiler will simplify them to their constant values rather than maintaining the longer expressions and operators:

```
final int five = 5;
final int four = five - 1; // Same as `four = 5 - 1`, or `four = 4`
final boolean val = five > four;
if(val) {           // Same as `if(5 > 4)`, or `if(true)`
     b = 5;
}
```

For further reading, check out the [Java Specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html). (Hat tip to Radiodef for finding the right section.)

Comment: Can you find a reference for this in JLS? I searched but I could not find it.

Comment: @merlin2011 Read the first comment under the question.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I included the link for completeness.

Comment: final boolean five = 5;  didn't know that was legal in Java ;)

Comment: LOL, Oops! Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

In this case:

```
if (false) b = 5;  // illegal
```

The compiler throws an exception since `if(false)` can be erased at compile time. It is futile to even analyze a block of code that won't be executed by any mean.

In this case:

```
int a = 5, b;
if (a > 10)
b = 4;
if (a <= 10)
b = 4;
```

The compiler cannot assure that the piece of code will be executed since `a` can change its value. In this case, you can *fix* it by marking `a` as final and assigning it a literal int value (which compiler can understand):

```
final int a = 5;
int b;
if (a > 10)
    b = 4;
if (a <= 10)
    b = 4;
```

But note that you can still break this code by giving `final int a` a value that the compiler cannot determine:

```
final int a = foo();
int b;
if (a > 10)
    b = 4;
if (a <= 10)
    b = 4;

//...

int foo() {
    return 5;
}
```

More info:

- [Java Language Specification. Chapter 16. Definite Assignment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html)